# Service name to port number mapping in Java

Tags: java, service, mapping, port

I'm working on a program to monitor the network connections on  a Linux machine. I'm reading basically the /proc files.

So my problem is I can get hold of the port number but I want to assign it it's appropriate service name (ignoring a service can be configured to run on a different port).

I don't want to put up an if-else

if(port==80) {protocol="HTTP";}

I want to have a lookup mechanism, that will accept the port number and return the service name. How can I achieve it ? I'm not looking for Hashtable or Map or properties files.

Comment: Why don't you want any of those options?

Comment: seems like you want a hash map, the key as port and the value the service

Comment: Uh... use a `HashMap` or `Map`?  There's a [list of port number assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) you can use to initialize the map.

Comment: But I will have to write down all the 1000 + port number adding codes...

Comment: Get good at parsing files, or using regex in your IDE to change copy-pasted data into source code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of linux machine it is .lsof can tell the  list open files including ports.You can then parse the output to get COMMAND TCP/UDP active ports in your system
for ipv4 ,for ipv6

```
lsof -Pnl +M -i4, lsof -Pnl +M -i6 respectivly

COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java      2432042      494   45u  IPv6 34535      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
sshd      201340        0    4u  IPv6  3123421      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
ntpd       5462       38   17u  IPv6     47202      0t0  UDP *:123
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is something like that, because an HTTP server which listens normally on port 80 can be set to listen to any port. In this case how will you know if it is HTTP service or another. Would you try to test for all existing protocols? I do not think so.